# How to reshape the flutter (dart) list

Tags: list, flutter, dart

Iam working with tflite library which requires an array with shape of [1, 150, 3] and i have 3 arrays of [150], when i try to make a list of the 3 list it shapes become [3, 150] and when using .reshape() it ruins the whole order i just need to reverse the dimensions of the list.

code snippets:

```
[rs, gs, bs].reshape([150, 3]
```

simple explanation
What happens:

```
before reshape: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

after reshape: [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]
```

What i need:

```
before reshape: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

after reshape: [1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [5, 10, 15]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the transpose method from: https://pub.dev/packages/matrix2d

```
List before = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
  ];

  print(before.transpose); //[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [5, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
List<List<T>> transposeList<T>(List<List<T>> input) {
  if (input.isEmpty) return input;
  int nRows = input.length;
  int nCols = input[0].length;
  List<List<T>> output = [];
  for (int col = 0; col < nCols; col++) {
    output.add([]);
    for (int row = 0; row < nRows; row++) {
      output.last.add(input[row][col]);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

for test: